# Removing data from redux and saving scroll position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, redux

I have an array of objects in redux which I am showing in my browser:

> [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…},
>   {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

```
object-0
object-1
object-2
object-3
object-4
object-5
object-6
object-7
object-8
object-9
object-10
object-11
object-12
object-13
object-14
object-15
object-16
object-17
object-18
object-19 <------ scroll position
```

On scrolling down, I am hitting an api and appending objects to the array. I have added a check that if number of objects in array becomes more than 20 then top 10 data should get deleted.

```
   case "DELETE_LISTING_TOP_PROFILES":

        let tempListingData = state[action.payload.listingId];          
        let tempListingProfiles = [...state[action.payload.listingId].profiles];            
        tempListingProfiles.splice(0,10);
            state
            ={
                ...state,
                [action.payload.listingId]:{
                    ...tempListingData,
                    profiles: tempListingProfiles
                }
            }
```

In my redux, the first 10 data gets deleted and my view becomes:

```
object-10
object-11
object-12
object-13
object-14
object-15
object-16
object-17
object-18
object-19
object-20
object-21
object-22
object-23
object-24
object-25
object-26
object-27
object-28
object-29 <------------ scroll position
```

As you can observe that the scroll position is now changed to `object-29`. I want it to remain at position 19, as follows:

```
object-10
object-11
object-12
object-13
object-14
object-15
object-16
object-17
object-18
object-19 <----------- scroll position
object-20
object-21
object-22
object-23
object-24
object-25
object-26
object-27
object-28
object-29
```

So, after deleting data from redux and adding some data to it, how can I save the scroll position?

Comment: Get scroll position before removing and apply it after removing document. `document.body.scrollTop = oldScrollTop;`

Comment: `Get scroll position before removing and apply it after removing document`? I am not removing/adding anything. It is managed by react-redux. Do I need to work on it manually?

Comment: You need to manage scroll position. I would handle it as side effect to redux action.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little bit? What does `side effect to redux action` mean?

Comment: To put it simply: before dispatching your action store scroll position to variable `const st = document.documentElement.scrollTop`. After the action (after list rerenders) `document.documentElement.scrollTop = st`.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about `getSnapshotBeforeUpdate()` lifecycle method ([official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#getsnapshotbeforeupdate)).

In pair with `refs` feature ([official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html)) it will help you to manage the scroll position right before changes are going to be applied to the `DOM` after changes in props, for example.

Comment: Never heard of the method. Is it new addition React lifecycle?

Comment: Yes, it seems like it was added in `React v16.3`. https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html